# No matching distribution found for django==3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, django, pip

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04, then made a virtualenv and tried to install Django with

```
sudo pip3 install django==3.0
```

but this generated the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==3.0 
(from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5,
 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, ...  2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==3.0
```

After searching, I think my `pip` version is too low, so it doesn't know about the new versions of Django. I tried to upgrade `pip` with

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

but this gave

```
WARNING: The directory '/home/hugh/.cache/pip' or 
its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. 
The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. 
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (20.0.2)
```

and I know that the `pip`'s lastest version is 20.0.2.

Why can't I install Django version 3.0?

Comment: Aside: _please_ don't `sudo pip install`. You're dumping user-installed packages from PyPI into the same place that OS-supplied Python packages go. Use virtualenvs or `--user`, depending on your exact use case.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for tip! But I also use virtualenv and `sudo pip install` in there. Is that also wrong for using right?

Comment: In a virtualenv you probably don't need `sudo`. Every time you us that command, try to think about the reason you need it. If you don't need it, don't use it.

Comment: I see. I just think there might be necessary to using 'sudo'. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure to create the virtualenv without `sudo` as well, or else you may run into permission issues :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to update `pip` to find new packages. It looks them up on PyPI.

[Django 3.0 requires Python 3.6 or greater](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/). [Ubuntu 16.04's `python3` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3) is for version 3.5., which [is supported by Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.2/).

Either upgrade your Python (I recommend using something like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or [`pythonz`](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) to easily decouple your Python version from your operating system) or use Django 2.2.

Comment: Oh thanks! My python version is 3.5.2. I wonder If I upgrade my python version, then I can use django 3.0 by `pip`?

Comment: I'm also getting this kind of error because i didn't activated my virtual env.